# YouTube API Subscribe to Channel returns TooManyEntries when I have only a few subscriptions. Anyone know why?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm developing a YouTube client using the C# API library.  On one account when I try to subscribe to a channel I get a TooManyEntries exception even though I only have 40 subscriptions. Anyone know why?

```
    var subscription = new Subscription();
    subscription.Type = SubscriptionEntry.SubscriptionType.channel;
    subscription.UserName = youTubeId;

    var response = _request.Insert(new Uri(YouTubeQuery.CreateSubscriptionUri(null)), subscription);
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you're trying to subscribe twice to the same channel. Is that it?